# List<E> doesn't like my custom class

Tags: java, list, generics

I am trying to declare a `list<Tuple<String,String,String>` where `Tuple<String, String, String>` is a class that I rolled myself.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Tuple<String,String,String>> Queries = new List<Tuple<String,String,String>>();
}
```

and this is the Tuple Class

```
public class Tuple<T1, T2, T3> extends java.lang.Object {

private final T1 first;
private final T2 second;
private final T3 third;

public Tuple(T1 first, T2 second, T3 third){
this.first = first;
this.second = second;
this.third = third;
}

public T1 first(){ return first; }

public T2 second(){ return second; }

public T3 third(){ return third; }
}
```

The error that I'm getting with List is

```
 Cannot instantiate the type List<Tuple<String,String,String>>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`List` is an interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) that can't be instantiated directly; try a concrete implementation, such as `ArrayList`:

```
List<Tuple<String,String,String>> Queries = new ArrayList<Tuple<String,String,String>>();
```

It had nothing to do with your custom class `Tuple` and everything to do with the `List` interface.

Comment: Forgot that `List` is just an interface in Java. This is what coding in C# for a long time does to you. Now I gotta wait 13 minutes